# creating a ComboBox in MS Access to hold distinct types

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a combo box in an `Access` form to display all the types in an inventory list (ex. cables, UPS, shelves, ...)

When I make the row source for the `ComboBox` I only want the type to display there once. The `ComboBox` will later be used to make a report for the different types of items in the inventory, so I will only need each type in the list box once. These types can be changed later so I want the list to be updated automatically.

Right now I have the `ListBox` displaying all the types multiple times, but when I try to change the row source to:

```
Select Distinct Inv_Type 
From Inventory;
```

I just get an empty `ComboBox`. But when I query that code I get get each type only once (this is what I want). What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting an empty `ComboBox`?

Comment: That should work. When you say empty, do you mean nothing shows in the dropdown? Did you create the combo using the wizards and modify? Did you create a fresh combo? Do you have a control source?

Comment: I created the combo using the wizard and then modified it, and yes nothing shows in the dropdown, it is just a white square.

Comment: Try adding a combo and just cancel when the wizard comes up. Then paste the sql from your working query into the Row Source of the new combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing as what Remou said; I created a `ComboBox` from scratch, without using the wizard first fixed my problem. Thanks!